# Copy Sql entries and add a time reference

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Good night,

I have two sql tables with these structures:

**Table 1:** Documents
Colums: name, length, price

**Table 2**: Documents_Archives
Colums: name, length, price, timestamp

I would like to copy specific entries from Documents 
to Documents_Archives using the Sql Query:

```
"INSERT INTO Documents_Archives * FROM Documents
WHERE ... "
```

It works, but how can I insert a timestamp reference in 
Documents_Archives using NOW() in the **same query** 
(where should I add the clause?).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `GETDATE()` or `NOW()` in the column list of your `SELECT` clause.

```
INSERT INTO Documents_Archives(name, length, price, timestamp)
    SELECT name, length, price, GETDATE() FROM Documents
    WHERE ...
```

*It's a good practice to specify the column names in your queries.*

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Documents_Archives
   SELECT *, GETDATE() FROM Documents
   WHERE ...
```

MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO Documents_Archives
   SELECT *, NOW() FROM Documents
   WHERE ...
```